# submit spark job in java application in subprocess, subprocess never exits

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I tried to submit a spark job to yarn cluster in another java application by creating a new subprocess in following way in Windows environment

```
        String command = "spark-submit --class package.runner --master yarn-cluster example.jar";        
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
```

I then submitted this java application on command, I checked the yarn manager UI and it shows the spark job finished running successfully. However, it seems the java application was blocked at p.waitFor(), anyone can point out what is the problem?

Comment: I can think of a few possibilities, but you can't confirm any of them yet because it's currently waiting for you to consume the outputstream. Use a [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and call `inheritIO()` (or start threads to actually consume it yourself) and I suspect your problem will go away.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch can you be a little specific? Do you mean I should call something like             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
 output = IOUtils.toString(reader); before p.wait()?

Comment: Yes. In a new thread too. The `inheritIO` call is how I would do it... because you also should read the error stream too.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch can you provide an example? I am new to this topic.